# React/ React Web Component/ is it possible to fetch data?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have introduced a React Component in my html website and have been trying to fetch data from a data.js file or data.json file to no result.

I have already tried:
`import {data} from './data'` when it was a data.js file and `import data from './data.json'` when it was a json file. I have also tried `data = require("./data.js")`. Each time it generates a RefferenceError: require is not defined.

I was hoping to bring data for posts to be generated with each data value. Maybe it is not possible in a simple React Web Component and without creating a whole React App. Not much I have found online to read about React Web Components and their ways.

The component:

```js
const names = [
  {
    name: "name",
  },
  "Ada Lovelace",
  "Grace Hopper",
  "Margaret Hamilton",
];

class TitleAddition extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: "",
      name: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {names.forEach((item) => {
          console.log(item);
        })}
        {`${this.props.name}`}
        {
          //some HTML
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And I was hoping to take the names array into a separate file - without any result.

Comment: How are you using React? Are you including it in your HTML or did you create a React project using `create-react-app`? Could you post your code? We need to be able to reproduce your error to be able to help.

Comment: @Designly I introduced a Simple Web Component in my HTML page without the npx create-react-app. The Component does not allow me to import or require anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is React when called a script on a standard HTML page doesn't have access to the filesystem. When you deploy a React app using `create-react-app`, it runs on a Node.js server, and the app has access to its own server root. If you want to do this as a web component, you'll need to create some sort of back-end API to fetch your data via `fetch()` function.

Now, if this is the only dynamic data your site is going to display, then I'd say go that route. If you plan to have other pages with dynamic data, then I highly recommend deploying your site as a full React app. Actually, I would recommend you use Next.JS, which is a layer on top of React. NextJS is more comprehensive and is production ready out of the box. And another huge bonus is you can deploy your app via the next-cli or automatically via Github commits to [Vercel](https://vercel.com), the makers of Next.JS.

In addition to all standard React libraries, Next.JS handles routing for you via the pages directory, so a URL on your site like `https://example.com/blog` would automatically route to `/pages/blog/index.js`. You can also have dynamic routes as easily as `https://example.com/blog/some-blog-slug` => `/pages/blog/[slug].js`.

Lastly, Next.JS has a built-in back-end express server API with the same filesystem-based routing as the pages directory.

Next.JS also does static site generation and can automatically rebuild portions of the site when the data sources changes. I highly recommend you check it out.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely check it out some day. I have just one question- maybe you know. Do I have to use some sort of backend even if I just want to import a javascript module into my React Web Component?

Comment: You can't use import or require on the client side because client-side JS doesn't have access to the filesystem, which would actually be your user's computer. Client JS cannot directly access the server. You could serve a JavaScript library from your web server or (preferably) load it from a CDN like CDNJS.

Comment: Ok, I guess this answers all my questions. I will just try add the content after the nodes for my posts have been created. Thank you so much!